# how to set buzzer on and off

Tags: arduino-nano, timers, piezo, buzzer, breadboard

I have a project that require me to use magnetic contact sensor. I will put the sensor at the door. So the idea is i want every time someone open the door, the buzzer will make a sound, but it will only stay for 3 seconds. When the door is close, buzzer will do nothing and when someone open the door again, the buzzer will make a sound for 3 seconds again. That is the loop. Here is my code. Sorry it's messy. I changed it few times and it still not working like what I want.

```
const int buzzer = 13; 
const int sensor = 4;

int state; // 0 close - 1 open switch

void setup()
{
  pinMode(sensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
{
  state = digitalRead(sensor);

  if (state == HIGH){
    tone(buzzer,1000);
    delay(3000);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }

  else{
    noTone(buzzer);
  }

}
```

Comment: You have to make your requirement more clear... what after the last 3 seconds?

Comment: You could change the delays `delay(1000);` and `delay(5000);` to `delay(3000);`? No? Or what exactly seems to be the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm still new here so I don't know how to write longer at my question or at least tell the detail. I'm using Magnetic contact sensor to put it at the door. So I want my buzzer to make a sound everytime someone open the door. But the sound will only stay for 3 seconds. Then when I close the door, and open back, it will make sound again.

Comment: being new here is no reason for not describing clearly what it is that you want to happen?

Comment: You have tried to cram your entire question into the subject line. That isn't all that helpful. Try reading [how to ask a good question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange). The code is good to see, but it would also help to have you describe what happens, compared to what you expect to happen.

Comment: If you want a delay of 3 seconds, why does your code have a delay of 1000ms? That is one second. This seems to be an obvious problem to fix.

Comment: i change it multiple times to test. to save time, i change the delay so i don't have to wait. if it work, i can just change the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have a state-machine problem such as this, I diagram it first - here's mine, based on how I understand your requirements:

[image: State Diagram]

Most state machines are only activated when an external event happens, so not much happens inside the state-boxes. But since your application only does this one thing, you can actually do your testing inside the states. This is the difference between between blocking- and non-blocking programming - we can afford to block (delay until something happens) because there is nothing else we have to do in the meanwhile.

And my code for the state-machine (which I haven't tested, but it compiles without error):

```
const int buzzer = 13; 
const int sensor = 4;

int state; // 0 close - 1 open switch

void setup()
{
   pinMode(sensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
{
   // Wait for sensor HIGH
   while( digitalRead(sensor) == LOW )
      ;

   // Sensor HIGH - Alarming
   tone(buzzer, 0.52);
   delay(3000);

   // Wait for sensor LOW
   noTone(buzzer);
   while( digitalRead(sensor) == HIGH )
      ;

   // (goes to Wait for sensor HIGH)
}
```

Comment: “diagram it first” is really the best advice.

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. I'm new here so i don't really understand the concept. i thought your code belong to other person, so i reply to him. I tried your code. It works but I don't want any sound when the sensor is LOW. Your code make the buzzer on for 3 seconds when the sensor is LOW and HIGH. I just want the buzzer turn on when the sensor HIGH. But your code is really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I edit your code a bit and it's working ! Thank you.

Serial.println("sensor: " + sensor);
   while ( digitalRead(sensor) == LOW );
    noTone(buzzer);
   

   // Sensor HIGH - Alarming
   tone(buzzer, 400);
   delay(3000);

   // Wait for sensor LOW
   noTone(buzzer);
   while( digitalRead(sensor) == HIGH )
      ;
   // (goes to Wait for sensor HIGH)